# Freeing memory of object in c++

Tags: c++, memory

```
void node::assign_childs()
{
    node *childs;
    childs = new node[8];
    .
    .
    .
    child_pointer = &childs[0];
}
```

I have trouble to find a way to free the memory of "child_pointer". "child_pointer" is defined in the the struct "node" as shown below.

```
struct node{
    vect p;
    vect norm;
    float s;
    unsigned char r,g,b;
    int fac_c;
    vector<int> cfac;
    bool isParent;
    bool filled;

    struct node* child_pointer;

    node(vect, float , vect );
    ~node();

    void assign_childs();

};
```

Using delete to free child_pointer does not appear to work, i have also tried delete [].

How could i create a destructor to free all child_pointers recursively down from the root node?

(this is a octree, so when i free a node all nodes within that node also gets freed)

if i have to change the way i assign/define child_pointer to make it possible to free it. How would i do that? using an array of 8 pointers is not a alternative, as it will use way to much memory.

here is the destructor i have tried.

```
node::~node(){
    if (child_pointer != NULL){
        delete [] child_pointer;
    }
}
```

doing this will crash my program with a segmentation fault.

```
node *octree(...);
.
.
.
delete octree;
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it appear to work?

Comment: no memory is freed, if i create and delete octrees memory accumulate and the program crash when i run out of ram.

Comment: Pretty sure it is safe to call delete[] on a NULL pointer so that if probably isn't needed.

Comment: BTW, there is a chance that those crashes are occurring because you have corrupted memory elsewhere and that they are only being caught when you free the memory.  What exactly is the error message on crash?  This might rule this possibility out.

Comment: Segmentation fault (core dumped) all that shows up in the terminal

Comment: hmm, made a small test program and it seems using delete[] in destructor works as expected, but not once the struct contain a std::vector. is there a known problem in deleting objects with vectors in it? varying size after push_back() maybe?

Comment: When you say "new node[8]" you ask the system for a single allocation capable of storing 8 nodes. Don't try to delete them individually, delete all of them with "delete[] childs;". Return them the way you acquired them or pay the price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the following in your destructor:

```
delete[] child_pointer;
```

Delete will call the destructor of the children, their deletes will call the destructors of the children's children etc.

Just showing how delete and delete[] is used:

```
int *foo = new int;
delete foo;

int *bar = new int[42];
delete[] bar;
```

Comment: I gave my very best to prevent that.

Comment: That was what i tought would work, but i cant make that work. update my question with the destructor i have.